# PBSPro Incorrect QList Entry Results in Q state

Tags: job-scheduling, pbs

We are using qlist to partition runs to a group of nodes submitted by particular user groups. The entire cluster is tested with a chron job that cycles through all of the nodes and for each job the related qlist has to be specified or the job will move into the Q state with the comment 'Not Running: Insufficient amount of resource: Qlist'.

It would be much easier to handle this user error situation from a test standpoint if the job went to a failed status instead of hanging in a Q state. It seems that anytime an 'insufficient resource' situation occurs, PBSPro would fail the job.  Why the Q state for what is clearly a failure that will never come out of Q?  Is there a way to change this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

A colleague (R. Powell) explained that PBSPro treats all insufficient resource issues as 'correctable' by queueing the job (ie waiting for the resource to become available) .  In this case, the scheduler is waiting for the nodes Qlist entry to change which is not so practical; but, treating all insufficient resource issues consistently is understandable.

It was also determined that a far better approach to our node directed testing is to run

```
pbsnodes [nodename] | grep resources_available.Qlist
```

to fetch the Qlist entry to be applied when running the actual test job.